# Update a project without deploying it

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an amazon chime sdk meeting where I have a `customConfig.json` with some specific configurations (like some functionalities being true or false, some timers, etc). How can I use AWS to update the configurations without deploying the code? Can I, for example, have this file somewhere else?